# SwiftからObject-Cを使う際のブリッジヘッダ自動作成が実行されない

Tags: swift, objective-c

SwiftからObject-Cで定義したクラスファイルを利用しようと思っています。
http://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/861d090a5471f4f0eeae
を参考にしていますが、
Swiftベースで開発を行い、Object-Cファイルを生成しようとすると
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
と画面がでてくるはずが出てきません。この作業前にObject-Cファイルの.hと.mを他プロジェクトからコピーしているからでしょうか？

本ブリッジヘッダーを自動で作成すると、Building SettingsのObjective-C Bridging Headerの設定などに自動的に設定されて非常に便利なのですが（以前、このパスがなかなかわからず苦労した経験もありまして…）

再度（？）自動設定するようにウィンドウを出すにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

なお、環境は以下の通りです。
XCode:7.1
Deployment Target: 8.0